# How do I write dollar signs ($) in posts without messing up the text formatting?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, formatting

I was writing an answer where I ended up using two dollar signs to indicate amounts of money. The text in between the two dollar signs became formatted, although I did not want the formatting I was just discussing money. Is there a way to get rid of the formatting given by symbols?

Example:

I have $10. With my $10 I am going to buy apples.

```
I have $10. With my $10 I am going to buy apples.
```

Comment: They should make ¤, ¥, 元, £, ₤, €, ₡, ₢, ₣, ₥, ₦, ₧, ₨, ₩, ₪, ₫, ₭, ₮, ₯, ₰, ₱, ₲, ₳, ₴, ₵, ₶, ₷, ₸, ₹, ₺, ₻, ₼, ₽, ₾, and even ₿ do formatting as well, so as not to single out users of $.  Although I think ¢ should format just like \$ but very tiny.

Comment: But that also offers a couple effective work arounds:  Write instead *“I have 1000¢*” or *“I have €8,48.”*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The formatting is [MathJax](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) and is pretty useful for complex math. If you want to use a normal dollar sign you have to "escape" the symbol. This means that you tell the interpreter "You know, the following is just a normal character. Not some formatting stuff like 'I want this italic', or 'I want this bold' or 'I want this in fancy math-whatever style'".

To escape the dollar sign simply use a backslash in front of it.

`\$` will produce $.

`I have \$10. With my \$10 I am going to buy apples.` produces

I have \$10. With my \$10 I am going to buy apples.

---

As I said in the text this can also be useful to turn off other formatting stuff. For example `\*` to get * instead of italic. This also means you need to write `\\` to get \, as `\` is the special character for escaping special characters.

For more examples about using MathJax you can also look on Meta [How do I add mathematical notation using Latex MathJax?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/607/how-do-i-add-mathematical-notation-using-latex-mathjax).